# How to avoid type conversion warnings?

Tags: ansible

When I use the [dconf module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/dconf_module.html) with a loop

```yaml
- name: dconf | modify settings
  dconf:
    key: "{{ item.key }}"
    value: "{{ item.value }}"
    state: present
  loop:
    - key: "/org/gnome/libgnomekbd/keyboard/layouts"
      value: "['us', 'se']"
    - key: "/org/cinnamon/panels-height"
      value: "['1:40']"
  tags: "dconf"
```

I get such warnings:

> [WARNING]: The value ['us', 'se'] (type list) in a string field was converted to "['us', 'se']" (type
>   string). If this does not look like what you expect, quote the entire value to ensure it does not
>   change.
>
> [WARNING]: The value ['1:40'] (type list) in a string field was converted to "['1:40']" (type string).
>   If this does not look like what you expect, quote the entire value to ensure it does not change.

I tried all possible ways to quote the value but without result

Comment: FWIW, quoting from [dconf](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/dconf_module.html#dconf-modify-and-read-dconf-database) "Value should be specified in GVariant format. Due to complexity of this format, it is best to have a look at existing values in the dconf database."

Comment: This didn't work for me. I eventually added `string_conversion_action = ignore` to ansible.cfg

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried

```yaml
value: "{{ item.value |string }}"
```

Comment: I tried the quote filter, but forgot about the Jinja built-in filters.
Thanks

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#string

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used static value and i got this warning. when I put my value in ' ' (Quotation) the warning didn't show any more.